# One ISR should be called, but both ISR has been called on Arduino UNO

Tags: interrupt, isr

I experimenting with the interrupt ISR using Arduino Uno. In my circuit, I am taking two mechanical switches that are connected with Uno's interrupt pins, pins 2 and 3, and also taking a built-in LED to confirm the ISR call.

My logic is when I press switch1 (which is connected to pin 3) or I press switch2 (which is connected to pin 2) LEDs should be turned on/off by the interrupt service routine.

My problem is that when I pressed switch1 and both ISR are called multiple times.

Here's my code:

```
const int mechanicalSwitchUpPin = 2, mechanicalSwitchDownPin = 3;

volatile byte stateSwitchUp = HIGH, stateSwitchDown = HIGH;

inline void upCallback()
{

  Serial.println("u");

  stateSwitchUp = digitalRead(mechanicalSwitchUpPin);

}

inline void downCallback()
{

  Serial.println("d");

  stateSwitchDown = digitalRead(mechanicalSwitchDownPin);

}

void setup()
{

  Serial.begin(115200);

  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(mechanicalSwitchUpPin, INPUT);

  pinMode(mechanicalSwitchDownPin, INPUT);

  digitalWrite(mechanicalSwitchUpPin, HIGH); //Enable Pull-Up resistor to this pin

  digitalWrite(mechanicalSwitchDownPin, HIGH);//Enable Pull-Up resistor to this pin

  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(mechanicalSwitchUpPin), upCallback, RISING);

  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(mechanicalSwitchDownPin), downCallback, RISING);

}

void loop()
{

  !stateSwitchUp ? digitalWrite(13, HIGH) : digitalWrite(13, LOW);

  !stateSwitchDown ? digitalWrite(13, HIGH) : digitalWrite(13, LOW);

  delay(1);

}
```

Here is the output during one short press/release of the button connected to pin 2:

```
17:10:06.231 -> d

17:10:06.231 -> u

17:10:06.231 -> u

17:10:06.231 -> u

17:10:06.231 -> d

17:10:06.231 -> u

17:10:06.231 -> u

17:10:06.231 -> d

17:10:06.231 -> u

17:10:06.231 -> u

17:10:06.231 -> u

17:10:06.231 -> u

17:10:06.231 -> d

17:10:06.231 -> u

17:10:06.264 -> u
```

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMPrIX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: you can use `pinMode(mechanicalSwitchUpPin, INPUT_PULLUP);`

Comment: Your switches are bouncing.  You need to debounce them.  You can do that in software or you can put a small capacitor across the button.  Google the term "debounce" for more information.

Comment: you can also use `digitalWrite(13, ((!stateSwitchUp) ? HIGH : LOW))`

Comment: You shouldn't have serial printing in your ISR.

Comment: First of all the bouncing phenomenon are really disturbing, there is A Guide to Debouncing by Jack G. Ganssle https://my.eng.utah.edu/~cs5780/debouncing.pdf. Second issue that contributes to the abnormal behaviour is the fact that this is the same interruptable. Doesn't matter SW1 is pressed or SW2 is pressed, both ISR going to be called. Am I right?